# How to run an exec() function as root and non-interactive?

Tags: c, permissions, exec, root, daemon

I am looking to `fork()` and exec with root privlages. It seems that privileges are not passed from the main thread once an exec function is called.

Now I have seen the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791210/c-programming-execute-another-program-with-sudo-privileges) that describes how to run a process as root, but when I try their solution..

```
char sudo[]="/usr/bin/sudo";
char pbin[]="/usr/local/bin/puppet";
execl(sudo,sudo,pbin,(char *)NULL);
```

The `sudo` command prompts for daemon's password. I am looking for non-interactive way to run the process as root. Is there anyway to do this short of removing Daemon's password?

Comment: If you could write a C program which fired up a root process without any security verification, then there wouldn't be much point having root privileges, right? If your program requires root privileges to work correctly, document that fact and let the user `sudo` tour peogram.

Comment: The initial process and thread that called `fork()` is ran using `sudo`. It seems these privileges are not passed when exec function is called.

Comment: Can you make your program SUID `root`?  If so, that works cleanly.

Comment: @benjamin: `execve` does not drop privileges. What evidence do you have that it is? If you start your executable as root, any children will also be run as root, so you should not need to use `sudo` in the exec.

Comment: The main process as well as the child process I want to create both need read access to `/dev/mem`. It seems the main process is able to read fine, but the child process cannot. I will get an access denied /dev/mem error

Comment: @benjamin: Works fine with my test. (I exec'd a `dd if=/dev/mem ...`, and it cheerfully read /dev/mem when I sudo'd my main program.) I don't mind pursuing this further, but it would be a different question, and you'd need to include an [mcve].

Comment: Just to be clear, `/dev/mem` is usually restricted to memory mapped I/O these days. I tested it on the zero page, which is still accessible (to root).

Comment: Ok so I found the issue. After reading some replies, I took another look at the library I was using that needed access to `/dev/mem` in the first place. It seems it would voluntarily drop privileges after initializing. This would explain my problem and am sure I can work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the premise of your question that,

> *"It seems that privileges are not passed from the main thread once an exec function is called."*

I wrote the following test code,

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
//    printf("starting");
    char sudo[]="/usr/bin/sudo";
    char pbin[]="mkdir";

//    printf("running test: %s %s",sudo,pbin);
    errno=0;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        int res = execl(sudo,sudo,pbin,"/bin/child",(char *)NULL);
//        printf("res:%d", res);
    }
    else {
        sleep(2);
        int res = execl(sudo,sudo,pbin,"/bin/parent",(char *)NULL);
//        printf("res:%d", res);
    }
}
```

And to my surprise, it worked without a problem, giving the following output:

```
$ sudo rm /bin/parent -rf ; sudo rm -rf /bin/child/
$ ls /bin/child/ -la
ls: cannot access '/bin/child/': No such file or directory
$ ls /bin/parent/ -la
ls: cannot access '/bin/parent/': No such file or directory

$ gcc main.c
$ sudo ./a.out

$ ls /bin/parent -la
total 8 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 11:42 . 
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar  6 11:42 ..
$ ls /bin/child -la 
total 8 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 11:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar  6 11:42 ..
```

As you can see there is a directory created by the parent process as well as the child process with root privileges.

---

Which got me thinking that your problem is in fact something else, as you state:

> *"The sudo command prompts for daemon's password. I am looking for non-interactive way to run the process as root. Is there anyway to do this short of removing Daemon's password?"*

What you really want is a **password-less sudo**, which can be obtained by running

```
sudo visudo
```

and then adding the line:

```
ALL     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

making your sudoers file looking like this.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```